# hierarchical treeview in c# Winforms with continent, nation, city

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a SQL table:

> REGION     NATION    CITY
>
> Europe     Austria   Wien
>
> Europe     Austria   Graz
>
> APA        Australia Sidney

Etc...etc...

Basically, region, nation, and city.

I would like to build a hierarchical Treeview like:

> -EUROPE
>
> --Austria
>
> ---Graz
>
> ---Wien
>
> -APA
>
> --Australia
>
> ---Sydney

I used Datatable to get data from a database.

Someone can help me with the cycle FOR and various nested if to accomplish that?
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication51
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            try
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("REGION", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("NATION", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("CITY", typeof(string));

                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Europe", "Austria", "Wien" });
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Europe", "Austria", "Graz" });
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "APA", "Australia", "Sidney" });

                foreach (var region in dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("REGION")))
                {
                    TreeNode regionNode = new TreeNode(region.Key);
                    treeView1.Nodes.Add(regionNode);
                    foreach (var nation in region.GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("NATION")))
                    {
                        TreeNode nationNode = new TreeNode(nation.Key);
                        regionNode.Nodes.Add(nationNode);
                        foreach (string city in nation.Select(x => x.Field<string>("CITY")))
                        {
                            TreeNode cityNode = new TreeNode(city);
                            nationNode.Nodes.Add(cityNode);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            treeView1.ExpandAll();
        }
    }
}
```